# Hibernate deadlock

Tags: hibernate, deadlock

Having a deadlock in webservice + hibernate... No idea why.

I have the following webservice code (core code of the function)

```
public String createImageRecipe(...)
{
    Session session = ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try 
    {
        session.beginTransaction();

        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, userid);

        // Create the recipe
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        ...
        ...
        ...

        session.save(recipe);
        session.save(user);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        session.update( recipe );

        // Add new entry to activity log
        Activitylog activityLog = new Activitylog(  user, 
                                                    (byte) ActivityTypeEnum.USER_SHARED_RECIPE.ordinal(), 
                                                    new Date() );
        activityLog.setRecipe(recipe);
        TimelineProcessor.saveTimeline( activityLog, null, true );

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        endMeasurement();

        return recipe.getRecipeid() + "," + recipe.getImageRecipeUrl();
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException e) 
    {
        ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Now the timeline thread (TimelineProcessor) does the following (after getting the message):

```
    Session session = ICDBHibernateUtil.getTimelineSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        ...
        ...
        ...

        TimelineId tlId = new TimelineId();
        tlId.setUserId(userId);

        User u = new User();
        u.setUserid(userId);

        Timeline tl = new Timeline(tlId, timelineData.getActivitylog(), u);
        session.save(tl);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while processing timeline :: ", e);
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

Exceptions from log:
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:435)

ERROR com.icdb.TimelineProcessor  - processTimeline - Error while processing timeline :: 
 org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not insert: [com.icdb.data.Activitylog]

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

ERROR com.icdb.TimelineProcessor  - processTimeline - Error while processing timeline :: 
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Will really appriciate help...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Hibernate is telling you what it doesn't like:

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

You are opening two sessions, and have a transaction in each, and when you save the new timeline in the second session, it has an activityLog, and that activityLog has a user and a recipe that stem from the first session. That's where Hibernate croaks.

I'm not sure i see what you are trying to accomplish. Is there a reason you need two separate sessions? Is the timeline something that's semantically associated with the recipe/user entities or is it more like a timestamp collection? In the former case you probably want to store user, recipe and timeline in one and the same collection, or else you'll end up with corrupt data if one transaction succeeds and the other one fails. In the latter case the Timestamp service should take value objects as arguments rather than entities, because you're probably going to want to access it from different parts of your application.

Comment: I see. Well the timeline is used to log all user activities (to display in timeline like in facebook...) I use it in a thread since I need service calls to be fast, and this can be done in BG. So as I understood from your answer - I should pass the Ids and e.g. create User u = new User(); u.setId( i_userId ), so if understood correctly then it should fix the issue?

Comment: That's how i would do it, especially since you have a SessionFactory and a TimelineSessionFactory, which is a hint that one day the timeline could end up getting stored on a completely different database server, and then you need to pass messages instead of entities anyway. How to implement it is another question: you can make the TimelineService take only raw data like ints and Strings, then some other part of the app can access it, too without having to know the User class. Or you can use a DTO copy, either made yourself, or using a tool like dozer. Both ways have merits.

Comment: BTW - will there be a problem to user same session in the thread?

Comment: Good question. Hibernate docs say sessions are not thread-safe. What happens if you do a session.getTransaction().commit() in one thread, and concurrently change entities in the other thread? I think if you tried that you'd have to rethink your transaction management.

Comment: That is a good point. So from what you suggest, I should have a different session for each service call?

Comment: At least for each thread, yes. And that's how i usually do it, one service call is normally one transaction, and often one session. I work a lot with JPA/JTA, where a session is called a persistence context and injected by the container, so normally i just don't have to care about db session management, but the bottom line is pretty much that.